# How to add expression parameter to Stimulsoft php js report?

Tags: javascript, php, reporting-services, stimulsoft

I'm using stimulsoft php js designer and I want to add an expression to a variable. However all the time it says undefined variable.

This is how i added expression

[image]

This is how it shows in the report window

[image]

Please help me to show current date as initial value of the variable. Thanks

Comment: Did you try Today without curly brackets?

Comment: It is an bug in stimulsoft report, i asked in their forum and they replied me that issue will be fixed in next release. Here is the reference - https://forum.stimulsoft.com/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=55499

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the {} and you will see the current date.

Comment: Nope, it is a bug - Here is the reference - forum.stimulsoft.com/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=55499